# Changing Graphics2D font from JComboBox

Tags: java, fonts, jcombobox

I've been trying to implement a JComboBox that has all of the available font families in it and then using an action listener to change the font of my Graphics2D variable.  I keep hitting this exception however:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.awt.Font
at Paint$TextBox$FontListener.actionPerformed(Paint.java:250)
```

Not entirely sure what is going wrong.  Here is the pertinent code.  Thanks for any help!

```
class TextBox {

    JFrame text = new JFrame("Text Box");
    JTextField TB = new JTextField();
    JLabel tb = new JLabel("                         Type Message: ");

    String[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    JComboBox font = new JComboBox(fonts);

    public TextBox() {
        text.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TB.addActionListener(new TextListener());
        font.addActionListener(new FontListener());
        text.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        text.add(tb);
        text.add(TB);
        text.add(font);

        text.setSize(400, 75);
        text.setLocation(250, 200);
    }

    public void visible() {
        text.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TextListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            yourText = (String)TB.getText();
        }   
    }   

    class FontListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
            JComboBox selectedFont = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            Font newFont =  (Font)selectedFont.getSelectedItem();
            Font derivedFont = newFont.deriveFont(newFont.getSize()*1.4F);
            graphics.setFont(derivedFont);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Font` object by passing the `String` in the constructor.

**[Font](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)** class has a constructor defined as [`public Font(String name,int style,int size)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)).

So you need to change

```
Font newFont = (Font)selectedFont.getSelectedItem();
```

to

```
Font newFont = new Font((String)selectedFont.getSelectedItem() , /*style*/ , /*size*/);
```